# Ubuntu partition: exited with non-zero exit status 32

Tags: partitioning, mount, fdisk

I'm unable to boot my laptop since the partition that Ubuntu is installed on reports: `exited with non-zero exit status 32: mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sda7, missing codepage or helper program, or other error`.

I've been trying to solve the problem with a live USB (Ubuntu 16.05):

`sudo e2fsck /dev/sda7` returns `/dev/sda7 has unsupported feature(s): metadata_csum`.

`sudo fdisk -l /dev/sda7` returns information on number of bytes and blocks so I reckon there's data on the partition.

I've read that a solution may be to use `sudo mke2fs -n /dev/sda7` but I'm afraid of data loss. Is there any way to restore the normal functioning of the partition and not lose the data?

The question has been also asked on https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/532085/311140.

Affected partitions are `/dev/sda5`, `/dev/sda7` and `/dev/sda8`.

Comment: Please don't crosspost with our sister site. Use AU or UL. Not both :)

Comment: Oh and be thorough: you left out large parts of the error message including version number and the notice `e2fsck: Get a newer version of e2fsck!`

Comment: if the filesystem error persists even when using 18.04 or 19.04 live, post dmesg first before running fsck

Answer (score 1):

Get a newer version of e2fsck. You can not use an older version of e2fsck to check a filesystem created with a newer e2fsck. Well, sometimes you can but not in this case.

I would assume that likely means you have an Ubuntu installed with a kernel >3.6 and use a live usb with kernel <3.6. Version 1.43 of e2fschk got metadata_csum added to the feature and that was around kernel 3.6.

So create a new live session. Live sessions should be used on the system you created them for. Not as a tool for every install. New install = new live session installer.

Comment: e2fsck by itself won't help if the kernel is also too old. needs a newer livecd in general, not much reason to still boot into a 16.04 from last century...

Comment: yeah that was what I was reading in my head as what I was typing >:-D came out wrong

Comment: I'm running `e2fsck 1.45.3 (14-Jul-2019)`. The output I get for `e2fsck /dev/sda5` is: `/dev/sda5: recovering journal
Superblock needs_recovery flag is clear, but journal has data.` Should I proceed with running the journal?